# github/gist - How to paste multi-line text (without line breaks getting removed)

Tags: firefox, github, gist

When i copy&paste multi-line text (from sublime3 or terminal) into Github/gist web inputbox i can see my text properly formatted (for a glimpse of a second). Then gist immediately removes all line breaks and fits everything into one line (see pic below). How can i prevent this?

Arch Linux, Firefox 58.0.2

picture: https://abload.de/img/gistx1rn6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting Firefox without any plugin ([safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)), because I just tested several copies from Sublime Text3 to a gist in Firefox (latest version), and I did not reproduce the issue.

My file can use CRLF or LF end-of-line characters, in both cases, the lines are preserved.

For testing, try those [Arch Linux commands](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Copying_text_from_a_terminal) to put a text in the clipboard, and see if the issue persists when said clipboard is pasted to the Gist.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I give up on this though. I tried several clipboard managers but it doesn't change anything. When i copy from Firefox (even one liners) text will be broken automatically into several lines (wtf?!) so there is an server-side AI/preprocessor that's running wild here. I spent too many hours on that already. Its frustrating and obviously their bug. Maybe i post it as a bug report to their forums later.